# Plot graph using maple or matlab

Tags: matlab, maple

I have tried using maple and matlab to plot this question but it seems to be unable to plot, would to ask if there is any ideas on plotting this question using maple or matlab?[image]

Comment: What is the $\mid$ doing at the end?  Do you want a matching one at the start?

Comment: sorry, the | was just a typo

Answer (score 5):

Here is Maple.  Note that (although the sum does converge at $t=0$) there seem to be numerical difficulties when $t$ is very close to $0$, so I started at $t=0.01$.

```
u:= Sum((1+(-1)^n)/(n*Pi)*sin(n*Pi*x)*exp(-n^2*Pi^2*t),n=1..infinity) +x+1:
plot3d(u,x=0..1,t=0.01..0.2);
```

[image]

EDIT: $u(x,0)$ should be a step function: essentially $3/2 + \lfloor x \rfloor$ ($x+1$ when $x$ is exactly an integer, but I'll ignore that).  So here is a better picture.

```
U:= proc(x,t) if t = 0 then 3/2 + floor(x)
  else Sum((1+(-1)^n)/(n*Pi)*sin(n*Pi*x)*exp(-n^2*Pi^2*t),n=1..infinity) +x+1 fi 
 end proc;
plot3d(U,-0.5 .. 1.5,0.. 0.2);
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be Gibbs phenomenon at work for $t=0$.

Comment: Yes, the Gibbs phenomenon affects partial sums of the series at $t=0$, which is the Fourier series of a discontinuous function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a MATLAB solution.

```
px = 2000;
pt = 1000;
niter = 100;
u = zeros(px,pt);
x = linspace(0,2,px);
t = linspace(0,1,pt);

for p = 1:px
  for q = 1:pt
    v = 0;
    for n = 2:2:niter
      v = v + 2/(n*pi) * sin(n*pi*x(p)) * exp(-n.^2*pi^2*t(q));
    end
    u(p,q) = v + x(p) + 1;
  end
end

[X,T] = meshgrid(t,x);

mesh(X,T,u)
```

[image]

Another solution, based on symbolic MATLAB,

```
syms x t n

u = symsum((1+(-1)^n)/(n*sym(pi)) * sin(n*sym(pi)*x) * exp(-n^2*sym(pi)^2*t),n,1,500) + x + 1;

fsurf(u,[0,0.2,0,2])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('x')
```

produces this plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I obtained this graphic with Mathematica in a few seconds...[image: 3D Plot truncating the sum to 50 terms]

The plot is for $t \in [0,1]$ and $x\in [0,2]$.

In matlab I suppose you can start by building a matrix with the function values at a given grid. Each function values is calculated by a finite sum (the exponential makes the series converge rather fast). That matrix can then be used to obtain the surface plot.

Comment: I would like to ask is it possible to plot using matlab or maple?

Comment: @Thanksforanswering it is possible, you just need discover what are the plot commands in matlab expecting to receive, and produce it. Computing function values can be achieved simply by working with a fixed number of terms in the series.

Comment: ok thank you, will try out using your idea